# Zendesk Feedback Tabs Trigger from Image to Link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zendesk

Hi I would like to put the trigger from image to link

right now the trigger of my support modal is from this

[image]

but i would like to put the trigger to regular link `<a href="#">Support</a>`

but this is all I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (typeof(Zenbox) !== "undefined") {
    Zenbox.init({
      dropboxID:   "123123123",
      url:         "link",
      tabTooltip:  "Support",
      tabImageURL: "https://p2.zdassets.com/external/zenbox/images/tab_support_right.png",
      tabColor:    "black",
      tabPosition: "Right"
    });
  }
</script>
```

could anyone help me please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the CSS that Zendesk will include by using:
https://caustic.zendesk.com/account/dropboxes/123123123/edit#advanced_customization

In here, you can hide the image block itself: #zenbox_tab img {display:none;}

Alternatively, you could remove the  element using jQuery.

Now you have an empty  for #zenbox_tab.  You can use jQuery to add your link with text as you posted above.  Your final step will be rotating the support link and making sure that works across all browsers/platforms.